# How to maintain car gas bottles safely

Tags: gasoline

A leaking gas cylinder basically contributed to the following tragic event:[gas](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2019-07-08/canberra-father-killed-remote-car-lock-explosion-coroner/11288828)

What is a good way to maintain your vehicle and gas bottle to stop this happening? Please note that "gas" in Australia is LPG [liquid petroleum gas] as in this report, not petrol. LPG is filled up from a different pump at a station. LPG is put into bottles like the one in the story.

Comment: The gas in this article is **acetylene** and **not** LPG, you need to make sure what you are saying. Vehicles designed to run on LPG have dedicated tanks fitted, usually outside the cabin compartment of the vehicle. However, some use the spare wheel well and have vents fitted for that purpose.

Comment: In the end it sums down to: Don't have flamable atmosphere inside your vehicle. Explosion proofing your vehicle isn't going to work.

Comment: I have never forgotten the "elf and safety" briefing from a grizzled engineer giving me a tour of a welding shop. "These brown cylinders are acetylene. If you are in this area and you hear one of them making a rattling noise, if you are *brave*, you will shout "ACETYLENE LEAK! EVACUATE!" and run like hell for the exit. But if you are ***wise***, you won't waste time and breath on shouting - just run like hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked article suggests that the deceased failed to properly close the valve on the bottle, which allowed the gas to escape. Certainly, the best way to maintain a gas bottle mounted in a vehicle is to close the valve.

Periodic checks of the transport system (hoses, valves, connectors) for leaks is advised. That would be as simple as a spray bottle of liquid detergent and water.

On a less practical level, one would keep the bottles and transport system outside of the cabin, which would allow leaking gas to dissipate more safely.

Answer (score 2):

As Mike says. LPG tanks are specialist tanks and are fitted on the outside of the vehicle. Any tanks stored inside, such as acetylene (as in this story) or propane (for cooking systems in RVs/motorhomes) should be stored in a safe position, with the valves properly closed and any connections regularly checked.

Permanently fitted propane tanks in motorhomes are, at least in the UK, required to be in an enclosed-from-the-cabin space with a vent at the bottom to the outside of the vehicle - this is because propane is heavier than air, so any leakage will drop through the vent and escape, rather than building up in the cabin.